# How to calculate accuracy of PCA?

Tags: pca

I want to compare different methods such as SVM and PCA to classify the data correctly. But I don't know how to calculate accuracy of PCA in R.

Following the article "Genetic classification of populations using supervised learning" (2011), I want to classify different populations using machine learning and PCA.

For SVM, I calculate accuracy with `confusionmatrix(table,test[,1])`. But for PCA I have a problem.

Comment: Not enough detail to know what you're doing. If it's machine learning then it's not clear why would it matter which method you use since the comparison is on predicted vs. actual values, such as accuracy tables. The method doesn't matter

Comment: Come on, you have already asked this question! This is a duplicate. Have you read the answer that you got there?